# What does this function converge to in $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with discrete metric?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

We're given this function

$f_n (x) = \begin{cases}
0 \ \mbox{ if $x <1/n$}\\
1 \ \mbox{ if $x \geq 1/n$}
\end{cases}$

I think it converges pointwise to

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 \ \mbox{ if $x < 0$}\\
1 \ \mbox{ if $x \geq 0$}
\end{cases}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Check again what happens at $x=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The actual pointwise limit would have $f(0)=0$.

Write down the definition of pointwise convergence. $f_n\to f$ in $x=x_0$ iff

$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N:\forall n>N, \vert f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)\vert<\varepsilon$$

In your case $x_0=0$ and the module would be $\vert 1-0\vert <\varepsilon$, which is false $\forall\varepsilon<1$.

Answer (score 0):

$f_{n}(0)=0$ $\forall n$ So $f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 \ \mbox{ if $x \le 0$}\\
1 \ \mbox{ if $x > 0$}
\end{cases}$.

Comment: Ah I goofed...the interval on which $f_n(x)=0$ is shrinking from the right side of $x=0$. Thanks!